Is there a difference in meaning between "eingeschlossen," "mit eingeschlossen" and "einschließlich?"
I am working on a translation of a game where in several places I need to translate "including [noun]," for example:

All of these, including the grail, are too bulky for your needs.


The whole process, including auditions, was coordinated entirely via email.

As far as I have been able to determine from dictionaries, "mit eingeschlossen" and "eingeschlossen" can both mean "including" or "included" and can both be put after the noun, much like in English where we can say "all expenses included." There is also the word "einschließlich," which again seems very similar except that it comes before the noun and takes the genitive. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Give some examples in German,  please. Mit eingeschlossen is doppelt gemoppelt.

Please don't use code formatting to format text. It is virtually unreadable on devices with smaller screens.

Use auch. That's most simple and most used. An alternative for pointing out single items is selbst.

All diese Sachen, selbst der Gral, sind zu sperrig für deine Belange.
Das ganze Verfahren, auch das Vorsprechen, ist komplett per Email abgewickelt worden.


In this case you can use einschließlich [noun] or inklusive [noun]. But in my opinion einschließlich sind better.
